# jQuery datatables plugin. bStateSave didn't work

Tags: jquery, mysql, view, datatable

i use jquery datatables  to show data

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({ 
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bSaveState": true
})
```

when i show data from myssql tables bStateSave works. I can reload page in browser and results in datatable stays the same (page, rows per page, filters, etc)

when i show data from mysql VIEW - it didn't work at all. I get table with results on 1 page and default settings (rows per page, clear filters, etc)

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML generation could depend on the source of the data - then you possibly have two different HTML table layouts.

Use a HTML template available from the plugin docs and fill it with your data and apply the settings for saving state in cookies. If that works, add your styles and change HTML according to your needs.  Use a HTML validator if you can to make sure that you always use jQuery DataTables plugin with valid HTML.

Temporarily disable jQuery UI ThemeRoller support and focus on the HTML markup DataTables basically needs to work. If 'state saving' works, reenable it and change markup to support ThemeRoller.

Excerpt from docs: http://www.datatables.net/usage/features

```
"bJQueryUI": true

Enable jQuery UI ThemeRoller support (required as ThemeRoller requires some slightly different and additional mark-up from what DataTables has traditionally used)
```

If you have different methods for HTML generation(mysql tables vs. VIEWS) then document it more detailed here together with generated HTML and the version of DataTables you are using.